# How can I center an Icon in the navbar-toggler (Bootstrap 5)?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I created a navigation Bar using bootstrap in Angular, however I have encountered an issue when adding a user icon as shown in the picture below, that problem does not happen if I instead use a text as shown Below (My Account). How can I fix this and make sure the user icon is centered aligned just like the rest of the links in the navbar?

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md bg-faded justify-content-center navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container">
      <a href="/" class="navbar-brand d-flex w-50 me-auto">

        <img
        src="assets/images/myImage.png"
        alt="my-image"
        loading="lazy" 
        class="logo"
      />

      </a>

      
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsingNavbar3">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100" id="collapsingNavbar3">
          <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-center">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>

          </ul>

          
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav ms-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
          <!--    <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
              </li>
            
               -->
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarScrollingDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                       
                    <img
                    src="assets/images/user.png"
                    alt="user-logo"
                    loading="lazy" 
                    class="logo"
                  />

                    </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarScrollingDropdown">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Login</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                    <!--  <li>
                          <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                      </li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item</a></li>

                      --> 
                  </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go...

The solution that @ethry suggested is not the best one (even though it works). Why using CSS if this can be done with Bootstrap? You just need to add `d-flex justify-content-center` to the `nav-item`.

See the snippet below.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md bg-faded justify-content-center navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand d-flex w-50 me-auto">
      <img src="assets/images/myImage.png" alt="my-image" loading="lazy" class="logo" />
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsingNavbar3">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100" id="collapsingNavbar3">
      <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-center">
        <li class="nav-item active d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav ms-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
        <!--  <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
              </li>
         -->
        <li class="nav-item dropdown d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarScrollingDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <img src="assets/images/user.png" alt="user-logo" loading="lazy" class="logo" />
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarScrollingDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Login</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            <!--  <li>
                      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item</a>
                  </li>
            -->
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<center>` tag to do this, but I would recommend using CSS instead.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md bg-faded justify-content-center navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container">
      <a href="/" class="navbar-brand d-flex w-50 me-auto">

        <img
        src="https://i-need-to-go.to-sleep.xyz/r/hi.png"
        alt="my-image"
        loading="lazy" 
        class="logo"
      />

      </a>

      
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsingNavbar3">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100" id="collapsingNavbar3">
          <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-center">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>

          </ul>

          
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav ms-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
          <!--    <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
              </li>
            
               -->
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarScrollingDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                       
                    <div style="text-align: center;"><img
                    src="https://i-need-to-go.to-sleep.xyz/r/hi.png"
                    alt="user-logo"
                    loading="lazy" 
                    class="logo"
                    
                    style="border: 1px solid lime; /*remove*/"
                  /></div>

                    </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarScrollingDropdown">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Login</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                    <!--  <li>
                          <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                      </li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item</a></li>

                      --> 
                  </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[The center tag has been deprecated, and is not supported by some browsers, so you should probably use the CSS option above instead of `<center>`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)

You can also remove that green border, I just put it there to show that it was actually centered.